# What is the null space of B?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

$A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $n \times m$ matrix.

It is given that $AB$ is non-singular.

What is the null space of $B$?

---

So, I have to find different vectors $x$ for which $Bx=0$. As I know that the order of B is $n \times m$, the vector $x$ will have n elements. I will get m equations, where the different products of the rows of $B$ and $x$ will be equal to $0$. But how do I find the required values?

Also, what is the use of $A$ matrix and the $AB$ matrix given as non-singular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that for any $v\ne 0$

$$ABv\neq 0 \implies A(Bv)=Aw \neq 0$$

that is $w=Bv \neq 0$ therefore $B$ is full rank column that is $\ker(B)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an arbitrary $x$ in the kernel of $B$, then $Bx=0$. Multiplying $A$ from the left on both sides of this equation gives $ABx = A(0) = 0$. So, we also have $x\in\ker(AB)$. But $AB$ is non-singular, which means that $\ker(AB)=\{0\}$. Hence, $x=0$.

This implies $\ker(B) = \{0\}$.